# PhpStorm open file in a wrong format

Tags: phpstorm

PhpStorm is opening a php as an SQL file. I checked the extension and it is php but PhpStorm insist to open it as an SQL. I've tried to clear the cache but no use.

Comment: You can initialize at the worst condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to settings and under Editor>file type.

add a file type that you want to add or may be you remove other file type.

Comment: Thanks, i found out for some reason somehow Phpstorm added the file name as a registered pattern for SQL files T_T .